# Is this conjecture well-formed?

Tags: notation, conjectures

For each positive integer $n$, one of these is true, where $a,b,c,...etc.$ are natural numbers:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
3^0\cdot{n}=2^a\\
3^1\cdot{n}=2^a-(3^0\cdot2^b)\\
3^2\cdot{n}=2^a-(3^0\cdot2^b)-(3^1\cdot2^c)\\
3^3\cdot{n}=2^a-(3^0\cdot2^b)-(3^1\cdot2^c)-(3^2\cdot2^d)\\
...
etc.
\end{array}
$$
(The specific values of $2^a, 2^b, 2^c, ...etc.$ dependent on $n$, e.g. all powers of two satisfy $3^0\cdot{n}=2^a$ for *some* value of $a$)

Or, more succinctly:
$$
\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}^+\exists{x}\in\mathbb{N}:n={2^{a_x}+\sum\limits_{y=0}^{x-1}-(3^y\cdot2^{a_y})\over3^x}
$$